# How to position layout according to orientation of tablet

Tags: android, android-layout, orientation-changes

I am creating demo app for tablet and also for mobile device.
Now there is one activity which has two `tabs`,So inside tab there is `ListView`.
 My Question is I want to show that `ListView` by some margin from left and right.So as orientation changes that margin value also changes
 I have read docs from [developer side](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) according to that Following is code snips for listview.
inside `res/layout-xlarge-land` folder

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="250dp" >
</ListView>
```

inside `res/layout-xlarge-port` folder

```
  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="100dp" >
</ListView>
```

Now problem is that when i change orientation of tablet it only takes portrait mode xml file and not landscape xml file. So how to resolve this problem.
 also included in manifeast file 
`<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />`
`<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:resizeable="true"/>` 
and for activity included 
`android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

layout-sw600dp-land for landscape mode in 7" tablet

layout-sw600dp-port for portrait mode in 7" tablet

layout-sw720dp-land for landscape mode in 10" tablet

layout-sw720dp-port for portrait mode in 10" tablet

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` line from your manifest. This stops the activity being destroyed and recreated.

Without it the OS will automatically destroy the activity and recreate it with the layout for the new orientation.

If you don't want to destroy it automatically you can catch the `onConfigurationChanged()` event and set the layout again manually there.

Comment: The activity is supposed to be destroyed and recreated. If you don't want it to do that then you must override `onConfigurationChanged (Configuration newConfig)` and set the content view again with the same layout, you will need to update any references to views as they will all be replaced